# JQuery tooltip customise hover items to appear above imagemap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltipster

[image: this is how I would like the hover to work]Help Please!

Trying to reposition the text when the user is hovering over the image map menu so that they are  all be unanimous and appear centred above the image.

I have been unable to reposition them as they individually react differently when I add the CSS.

Ideally I would like to have the hover box in the borderless theme in black so only the text appears in white above the image map when the users hovers between menu items.

Thanks in advance!

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
  theme: ['tooltipster-noir', 'tooltipster-noir-customized']
  });
 });
```

```css
.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-noir.tooltipster-noir-customized   .tooltipster-box {
background:black;
Border:0;

 }



.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-noir.tooltipster-noir-customized .tooltipster-content {
    color: white;
   font-family: "josefin sans";
   font-size: 3rem;
Border:0;

   

     }
```

```html
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/dist/css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRo8A.png" id="logo" style="width: 260px; max-width: 100%; height: auto;" alt="" usemap="#map" />

<map name="map">
<area shape="circle" coords="243,132,41" href="Konpakutotrack.html" class="tooltip" title="Track" />
<area shape="circle" coords="189,223,41" alt='' href="Konpakutoinsurance.html"  class="tooltip" title="Insurance Cov."/>
<area shape="circle" coords="69,205,29" alt='' href='Konpakutohealth.html' class="tooltip" title="Health"/>
<area shape="circle" coords="9,131,42" alt='' href='Konpakutounlocklock.html'  class="tooltip" title="Lock" />
<area shape="circle" coords="128,49,81" alt='' href='index.html' class="tooltip" title="Home" />
</map>


</div> 
  
       
 </body>

  
</html>
```

Comment: Adding `border: 0;` to your `.tooltipster-noir-customized` css should do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks I'll give that a try

Comment: Hi Azs06  that didnt work

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding what you are trying to achieve, you want tooltip without any border or background just the text? here is an example of how it looks without border https://output.jsbin.com/sopojeh/1, maybe this is not what you are after.

Comment: I would like to have no border, however primarily I would like all the hover elements e.g track, health, insurance cov to all appear in the same place directly above the image map. so that when the user is hovering over an element a div fixed directly to a position above the image map will change depending on what the user hovers over :) hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Ive added an image above which shows how I would like the positioning of the tooltip hover hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a one way to do it, using CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
  theme: ['tooltipster-noir', 'tooltipster-noir-customized']
  });
 });
```

```css
.container{
 position: relative;
 width: 260px;
 padding: 100px 20px 20px;
 background: #000;
}
.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-noir.tooltipster-noir-customized   .tooltipster-box {
color: #fff; 
border: 0; 
position: fixed;
top: 5px;
left: 120px;
background: transparent; 
 }
.tooltipster-arrow{
 display: none;
}


.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-noir.tooltipster-noir-customized .tooltipster-content {
    color: white;
   font-family: "josefin sans";
   font-size: 24px;

     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<link href="https://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/dist/css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
</head> 
<body>
<div class="container">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRo8A.png" id="logo" style="width: 260px; max-width: 100%; height: auto;" alt="" usemap="#map" />
<map name="map">
<area shape="circle" coords="243,132,41" href="Konpakutotrack.html" class="tooltip" title="Track" />
<area shape="circle" coords="189,223,41" alt='' href="Konpakutoinsurance.html"  class="tooltip" title="Insurance Cov."/>
<area shape="circle" coords="69,205,29" alt='' href='Konpakutohealth.html' class="tooltip" title="Health"/>
<area shape="circle" coords="9,131,42" alt='' href='Konpakutounlocklock.html'  class="tooltip" title="Lock" />
<area shape="circle" coords="128,49,81" alt='' href='index.html' class="tooltip" title="Home" />
</map> 
</div>  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<script src="https://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much azs06, this is exactly what I wanted it works perfectly :)

Comment: Happy to help :-)